# Add latest tweet as pure text on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I've got an HTML/CSS website and want to add my latest tweet in the footer section, a few notes:

- I don't like the look of the available twitter widgets on their website
- I just want something that will show Only my latest tweet as text (just the last one, not several), then I'll go around adding a background and customize the fonts through CSS.
- I'm still a beginner when it comes to web development, so don't have any experience with JQuery/javascripts, so if the solution is done by those I'd really appreciate it if you keep it simple and easy to understand.

I tried following this guide exactly as mentioned in the steps but it didn't work, simply nothing was shown:

http://www.webdesigndev.com/programming/how-to-display-your-last-tweet-using-javascript-and-the-twitter-api

Maybe it's an outdated method of doing such thing, I'm not really sure, I don't want this exact method to work, just anything to get the job done.

Any help would be really appreciated guys.

Comment: If you haven't already looked, you should check out the official Twitter API documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.  Go into your editor and replace the "" from what the source code you copy is using and replace it with real "". On all 3 lines

Got it to work for me

Comment: That did help, thank you! Only issue now is that when the page reaches the javascript part, the entire lower section of my dark themed website becomes white as it's loading, is there any way to prevent this by adjusting when the javascript loads somehow? Like for example let the script load when the entire page has loaded or something?

Comment: I load my js file at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You need to load the script where you want it to show. I took out the type=JavaScript too, as long as you are using HTML 5.  Look for anything else that might interfere with the script. Could you put a checkmark next to my answer if it worked?

Comment: This will sound totally newbish, but if I loaded the script below, how do I call it to function in the div section that I created in HTML? I accepted your answer, this might be going a little off topic but I'd appreciate any input about it. I'm using xhtml btw.

Comment: When I typed that I was referring to my jquery link then it wouldnt let me edit it.  My mistake.  I cant duplicate your problem but it certainly sounds like something is interfering with the link to twitter. All I can suggest is posting your html to the point of the script maybe someone can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your website on the place you need it:

```
<div id=”twitter_update_list”>
  <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js”></script>
  <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/[yourusername].json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1″></script>
</div>
```

Comment: But that's the exact code that's mentioned in the link I posted which didn't work for me.

Comment: Yeah - just noticed that - but I tried the Code and it worked perfectly fine - http://www.flobauer.at/twitter.html

Comment: Might want to check with firebug, when I tried to use it I got a 403 forbidden error in the console for both lines of code

Comment: you're right with the quotes - don't know what happened by copying it!